# python selenium Attribute error in a while loop while using .click() while trying an except

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, selenium-chromedriver, try-except

```
        i=1

        while i<=numberCountGlobal:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("i is: ",i)
            self.tempString='//*[@id="grid-view"]/div[{}]/div[4]/button'.format(i)
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.tempString).click()
                print("button press sucessfull")

            except NoSuchAttributeException:
                print("Nothing here.. skipping")

            i+=1
```

error:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.tempString).click()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

This throws an attributeError but when im trying to expect it, it just doesn't work. When I close my browser, then the code error comes up in the console.

It`s trying to click a specific button in a website, there are either a lot of them or a few of them hence I used a while loop to loop through all buttons that are "there"

if for example.. I remove the `.click()` and just leave it as it is, it still gives no error until i close my browser, then it comes. Also i am not sure why it is giving an attribute error when the error should rather be a `NoSuchElementException` as this element IS NOT THERE when there is no button! (yes I have tried this as well and it still has the same issue) as well as `except AttributeError`

So if a button is no there, the xpath will not work as the element is no there, and if it is, it will be in the correct index, so if the 5th button was there, it will be: `//*[@id="grid-view"]/div[5]/div[4]/button`

Comment: what was the ttribute error

Comment: coul;d you remove try-expect and add what error you get

Comment: could you add full code with method

Comment: Thanks PDHide for replying but I figured it out and published the answer, a implicit wait is required.

Comment: Could you make your answer more helpful for stackover flow community , this answer isn't helpful . The real question is why was it saying nonetype , find element shouldn't return nonetype

Comment: Hi, I changed my answer and added the right code, im also confused on that as well about it being nonetype but after adding this it did not return it as nonetype.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know selenium, but if the exception isn't catching it, then that means that you have the wrong type of exception. The reason that it is an "attribute error" rather than the one that you stated is that "self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.tempString)" is returning as "None." Based on my work with BeautifulSoup, this could be because it couldn't find an element with the xpath of your self.tempString. The attribute error is derived because python is interpreting it as "None.click()," when there clearly isn't a click attribute for None.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Hi, so i understand what i mean but i tried to print just that without .click(), it does not work, however AFTER i close my browser, THEN it returns none

Comment: What happens when you print(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.tempString) ?

Comment: issue was found and added as the answer, another part to my issue was that the website was loading too slowly so adding in the wait fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:
add an implicit wait just after the try:

````
        i=1

        while i<=numberCountGlobal:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("i is: ",i)
            self.tempString='//*[@id="grid-view"]/div[{}]/div[4]/button'.format(i)
            try:
                self.driver.implicitly_wait(1)
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.tempString).click()
                print("button press sucessfull")

            except NoSuchAttributeException:
                print("Nothing here.. skipping")

            i+=1```
````